# How do I add more accounts and outputs to my password authentication program?

Tags: java

It's just as the question is titled. The area where I'm having an issue is with the if/else properties.. and also, how would I go about changing it from an API interface to an array type interface? Sorry if my formatting is poor. Feel free to correct me.

Program corrected and running how it is intended:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;  // Needed for the Scanner class

public class PasswordVerifier2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;

    System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();

if (authenticate1(input)) {

        System.out.println("This program is working if this text is found within outputfile.txt.");

        File file = new File("outputfile.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
        System.setOut(ps);
        System.out.println("This program is working if this text is found within outputfile.txt.");

}else if (authenticate2(input)) {

        System.out.println("It works.");

}else{
System.out.println("Error: Wrong password.");
}
}

private static boolean authenticate1(String password1) {

    return ((password1.length() == 6)
            && (password1.matches("beep11"))
            && (password1.matches("beep11"))
            && (password1.matches("beep11")));
}

private static boolean authenticate2(String password2) {

            return ((password2.length() == 6)
            && (password2.matches("beep22"))
            && (password2.matches("beep22"))
            && (password2.matches("beep22")));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using/applying one of the two methods to authenticate the user then you can use `if.. else if`, e.g.:

```
if (authenticate1(input)) {
// some code
}else if (authenticate2(input)) {
//some code
}else{
System.out.println("Error: Wrong password.");
}
```

**EDIT**

To get rid of compilation error at `authenticate2`, you either need to move that `authenticate2` to your main class or include the class name in method call, e.g.

change

`if (authenticate2(input)) {`

to

`if (authenticate2.authenticate2(input))`

This will make sure the control does not go into second `if` block if first one is successful and vice versa.

Comment: It won't work and I have errors for the authentication class fetchers. Back to square 1. There is still just that error at authentication 2.

Comment: I updated the code. Now I'm having issues where the authentication2 passwords are located. How do I make this work? There are no errors in the main string anymore.

Comment: The }else if { insertion worked, and I changed the authentication2 string to String password2, and it seems to be working. Thanks, everyone. I'll update the code to the current working version.

Comment: Glad it worked. You can accept my answer if you think it has helped you.